Why do I keep getting a Valgrind set address range perms warning in my code?
I don't see what I could possibly be doing wrong to keep getting this valgrind error. I'm not leaking any memory..
In my project, I have to implement a graph, a fundamental graph algorithm, and have a working maps application that can find paths in real data. I cannot use new in this project, nor edit the signatures of the public member functions, or add public member variables of the graph class. I may add private member variables and functions. I may not modify the signatures of other functions. However, I may add additional helper functions. I may only modify graph.h and application.cpp.
My graph class represents graphs with all of the following properties:

Directed – edges have a start and an end.

Simple – for any two nodes A and B, there is at most one directed edge from A to B.

The directed edge from B to A is a separate edge that can also exist. ● Weighted – each edge has data associated with it.



The goal is to represent a map using a graph. Vertices represent places people can exist, and edges between vertices show how people can move between these places. A node in OSM (OpenStreetMaps) is a single point in the real world, and consists of 3 values that we care about:

ID (long long, unique identifier)

Latitude (double)

Longitude (double)


OSM’s data tells me that the starting and ending nodes happen to be part of other ways. This is how I connect footpaths to other footpaths, and build up the entire graph. The other kind of way I'm interested in is a building. OSM defines a building by the nodes in its perimeter. For example, a college campus could be made up of 13 nodes, despite seeming rectangular-ish. To simplify my navigation problem, I have to convert each building to a single node by averaging the coordinates of the nodes in its perimeter. Because these nodes aren’t connected to the graph by footways, I have tol add new edges from building centers to nearby footway nodes.
I can only modify graph.h and application.cpp.
My graph.h:
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/// @brief Simple directed graph using an adjacency list.
/// @tparam VertexT vertex type
/// @tparam WeightT edge weight type
template <typename VertexT, typename WeightT>
class graph {
   private:
    // TODO_STUDENT
    /*We are dealing with an adjacency list representation. The elements
      are not required to be sorted based on keys*/
    unordered_map<VertexT, unordered_map<VertexT, WeightT> > adjacencyList;

   public:
    /// Default constructor
    graph() {
        // No initialization needed for the adjacency list
    }

    /// @brief Add the vertex `v` to the graph, must run in at most O(log |V|).
    /// @param v
    /// @return true if successfully added; false if it existed already
    bool addVertex(VertexT v) {
        // TODO_STUDENT
        return adjacencyList.emplace(v, unordered_map<VertexT, WeightT>()).second;
    }

    /// @brief Add or overwrite directed edge in the graph, must run in at most O(log |V|).
    /// @param from starting vertex
    /// @param to ending vertex
    /// @param weight edge weight / label
    /// @return true if successfully added or overwritten;
    ///         false if either vertices isn't in graph
    bool addEdge(VertexT from, VertexT to, WeightT weight) {
        // TODO_STUDENT
        if (adjacencyList.find(from) != adjacencyList.end() && adjacencyList.find(to) 
            != adjacencyList.end()) {
                adjacencyList[from][to] = weight;
                return true;
        }    
        return false;
    }

    /// @brief Maybe get the weight associated with a given edge, must run in at most O(log |V|).
    /// @param from starting vertex
    /// @param to ending vertex
    /// @param weight output parameter
    /// @return true if the edge exists, and `weight` is set;
    ///         false if the edge does not exist
    bool getWeight(VertexT from, VertexT to, WeightT& weight) const {
        // TODO_STUDENT
        auto fromIt = adjacencyList.find(from);
        if (fromIt != adjacencyList.end()) {
            auto toIt = fromIt->second.find(to);
            if (toIt != fromIt->second.end()) {
                weight = toIt->second;
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// @brief Get the out-neighbors of `v`. Must run in at most O(|V|).
    /// @param v
    /// @return vertices that v has an edge to
    set<VertexT> neighbors(VertexT v) const {
        set<VertexT> S; //A set that will store the out-neighbors of the vertex v
        
        // TODO_STUDENT
        auto it = adjacencyList.find(v); 

        if (it != adjacencyList.end()) {
            for (const auto& neighbor : it->second) {
                S.insert(neighbor.first);
            }
        }
        return S; //Returns the out-neighbors of the vertex
    }

    /// @brief Return a vector containing all vertices in the graph
    vector<VertexT> getVertices() const {
        // TODO_STUDENT
        vector<VertexT> vertices; //Vector that will store all vertices present in the graph
        for (const auto& pair : adjacencyList) {
            vertices.push_back(pair.first);
        }
        return vertices;
    }

    /// @brief Get the number of vertices in the graph. Runs in O(1).
    size_t NumVertices() const {
        return adjacencyList.size();
    }

    /// @brief Get the number of directed edges in the graph. Runs in at most O(|V|).
    size_t NumEdges() const {
        size_t numEdges = 0;
        for (const auto& pair : adjacencyList) {
            numEdges += pair.second.size(); // Increment by the number of outgoing edges for each vertex
        }
        
        return numEdges;
    }
};

My application.cpp:
#include "application.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip> /*setprecision*/
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

#include "dist.h"
#include "graph.h"
#include "osm.h"
#include "tinyxml2.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;

double INF = numeric_limits<double>::max(); 

graph<long long, double> buildGraph(
    const map<long long, Coordinates>& Nodes,
    const vector<FootwayInfo>& Footways,
    const vector<BuildingInfo>& Buildings) {
    graph<long long, double> G;
    
    // TODO_STUDENT
    for (const auto& node : Nodes) {
        G.addVertex(node.first);
    }

    for (const auto& footway : Footways) { //For each footway
        for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < nodes.size(); ++i) {
            long long from = nodes.at(i); 
            long long to = nodes.at(i + 1); 
            double distance = distBetween2Points(Nodes.at(from).Lat, Nodes.at(from).Lon, 
            Nodes.at(to).Lat, Nodes.at(to).Lon);
            G.addEdge(from, to, distance);
            G.addEdge(to, from, distance);
        }
    }

    for (const auto& building : Buildings) {
        G.addVertex(building.Coords.ID);

        for (const auto& node : Nodes) {
            if (node.second.OnFootway && distBetween2Points(building.Coords.Lat, building.Coords.Lon, node.second.Lat, node.second.Lon) < 0.041) {
                G.addEdge(building.Coords.ID, node.first, distBetween2Points(building.Coords.Lat, building.Coords.Lon, node.second.Lat, node.second.Lon));
                G.addEdge(node.first, building.Coords.ID, distBetween2Points(building.Coords.Lat, building.Coords.Lon, node.second.Lat, node.second.Lon)); // Bidirectional edge
            }
        }
    }
    return G;
}

class prioritize {
    public:
    bool operator()(const pair<double, long long>& p1, const pair<double, long long>& p2) const {
        return p1.first > p2.first; // Compare based on the first element (distance)
    }
};

vector<long long> dijkstra(
    const graph<long long, double>& G,
    long long start,
    long long target,
    const set<long long>& ignoreNodes) {
    vector<long long> path; //Vector to sore the shortest path

    // TODO_STUDENT
    /*Priority queue to store vertices with their respective distances*/
    priority_queue<pair<double, long long>, vector<pair<double, long long> >, prioritize> worklist;

    unordered_map<long long, double> distances;
    unordered_map<long long, long long> previous;
    set<long long> visited;

    if (start == target) {
        return {start};
    }

    for (long long vertex : G.getVertices()) {
          distances[vertex] = INF; // Set initial distance to
    }

    distances[start] = 0; //Sets distance to start the vertex to 0
    worklist.push(make_pair(0, start)); //Push the start vertex to the priority queue
    
    while (!worklist.empty()) {
        long long current = worklist.top().second; 
        double distance = distances.at(current);

        worklist.pop();  // Pops the vertex with the smallest distance
        
        if(current == target) { break; }
        if (visited.count(current)) continue;
        visited.insert(current);

        // Update distances of neighbors
        for (long long neighbor : G.neighbors(current)) {
            // Skip ignored nodes
            if (ignoreNodes.count(neighbor) && neighbor != target) continue;
    
            double weight = 0.0;
            double edgeExists = G.getWeight(current, neighbor, weight);
          
            if (!edgeExists) continue; 

            if (distance + weight < distances[neighbor] || distances.count(neighbor) == 0) {
                distances[neighbor] = distance + weight;
                previous[neighbor] = current; // Update previous vertex
                worklist.push(make_pair(distances[neighbor], neighbor));
            }
        }
    }

    long long current = target;
    
    while (current != start) {
        path.push_back(current);

        current = previous[current]; 
    }
    path.push_back(start);
    reverse(path.begin(), path.end()); // Reverse the path to get the correct order

    return path;
}

double pathLength(const graph<long long, double>& G, const vector<long long>& path) {
    double length = 0.0;
    double weight = 0.0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < path.size(); i++) {
        bool res = G.getWeight(path.at(i), path.at(i + 1), weight);
        assert(res);
        length += weight;
    }
    return length;
}

void outputPath(const vector<long long>& path) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < path.size(); i++) {
        cout << path.at(i);
        if (i != path.size() - 1) {
            cout << "->";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void application(
    const vector<BuildingInfo>& Buildings,
    const graph<long long, double>& G) {
    string person1Building, person2Building;

    set<long long> buildingNodes;
    for (const auto& building : Buildings) {
        buildingNodes.insert(building.Coords.ID);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter person 1's building (partial name or abbreviation), or #> ";
    getline(cin, person1Building);

    while (person1Building != "#") {
        cout << "Enter person 2's building (partial name or abbreviation)> ";
        getline(cin, person2Building);

        //
        // find the building coordinates
        //
        bool foundP1 = false;
        bool foundP2 = false;
        Coordinates P1Coords, P2Coords;
        string P1Name, P2Name;

        for (const BuildingInfo& building : Buildings) {
            if (building.Abbrev == person1Building) {
                foundP1 = true;
                P1Name = building.Fullname;
                P1Coords = building.Coords;
            }
            if (building.Abbrev == person2Building) {
                foundP2 = true;
                P2Name = building.Fullname;
                P2Coords = building.Coords;
            }
        }

        for (const BuildingInfo& building : Buildings) {
            if (!foundP1 &&
                building.Fullname.find(person1Building) != string::npos) {
                foundP1 = true;
                P1Name = building.Fullname;
                P1Coords = building.Coords;
            }
            if (!foundP2 && building.Fullname.find(person2Building) != string::npos) {
                foundP2 = true;
                P2Name = building.Fullname;
                P2Coords = building.Coords;
            }
        }

        if (!foundP1) {
            cout << "Person 1's building not found" << endl;
        } else if (!foundP2) {
            cout << "Person 2's building not found" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Person 1's point:" << endl;
            cout << " " << P1Name << endl << " " << P1Coords.ID << endl;
            cout << " (" << P1Coords.Lat << ", " << P1Coords.Lon << ")" << endl;
            cout << "Person 2's point:" << endl;
            cout << " " << P2Name << endl << " " << P2Coords.ID << endl;
            cout << " (" << P2Coords.Lat << ", " << P2Coords.Lon << ")" << endl;

            string destName = "";
            Coordinates destCoords;

            Coordinates centerCoords = centerBetween2Points(
                P1Coords.Lat, P1Coords.Lon, P2Coords.Lat, P2Coords.Lon);

            double minDestDist = numeric_limits<double>::max();

            for (const BuildingInfo& building : Buildings) {
                double dist = distBetween2Points(
                    centerCoords.Lat, centerCoords.Lon,
                    building.Coords.Lat, building.Coords.Lon);
                if (dist < minDestDist) {
                    minDestDist = dist;
                    destCoords = building.Coords;
                    destName = building.Fullname;
                } 
            }

            cout << "Destination Building:" << endl;
            cout << " " << destName << endl;
            cout << " " << destCoords.ID << endl; 
            cout << " (" << destCoords.Lat << ", " << destCoords.Lon << ")" << endl;
            
            vector<long long> P1Path = dijkstra(G, P1Coords.ID, destCoords.ID, buildingNodes);
            vector<long long> P2Path = dijkstra(G, P2Coords.ID, destCoords.ID, buildingNodes);
            
            // This should NEVER happen with how the graph is built
            if (P1Path.empty() || P2Path.empty()) {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "At least one person was unable to reach the destination building. Is an edge missing?" << endl;
                cout << endl;
            } else {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Person 1's distance to dest: " << pathLength(G, P1Path);
                cout << " miles" << endl;
                cout << "Path: ";
                outputPath(P1Path);
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Person 2's distance to dest: " << pathLength(G, P2Path);
                cout << " miles" << endl;
                cout << "Path: ";
                outputPath(P2Path);
            }
        }

        //
        // another navigation?
        //
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter person 1's building (partial name or abbreviation), or #> ";
        getline(cin, person1Building);
    }
}

My osm.h:
/*osm.h*/

#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "tinyxml2.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;

//
// Coordinates:
//
// the triple (ID, lat, lon)
//
struct Coordinates {
    long long ID;
    double Lat;
    double Lon;
    bool OnFootway;

    Coordinates() {
        ID = 0;
        Lat = 0.0;
        Lon = 0.0;
        OnFootway = false;
    }

    Coordinates(long long id, double lat, double lon) {
        ID = id;
        Lat = lat;
        Lon = lon;
        OnFootway = false;
    }
};

//
// FootwayInfo
//
// Stores info about one footway in the map.  The ID uniquely identifies
// the footway.  The vector defines points (Nodes) along the footway; the
// vector always contains at least two points.
//
// Example: think of a footway as a sidewalk, with points n1, n2, ...,
// nx, ny.  n1 and ny denote the endpoints of the sidewalk, and the points
// n2, ..., nx are intermediate points along the sidewalk.
//
struct FootwayInfo {
    long long ID;
    vector<long long> Nodes;

    FootwayInfo() {
        ID = 0;
    }

    FootwayInfo(long long id) {
        ID = id;
    }
};

//
// BuildingInfo
//
// Defines a campus building with a fullname, an abbreviation (e.g. SEO),
// and the coordinates of the building (id, lat, lon).
//
struct BuildingInfo {
    string Fullname;
    string Abbrev;
    Coordinates Coords;

    BuildingInfo() {
        Fullname = "";
        Abbrev = "";
        Coords = Coordinates();
    }

    BuildingInfo(string fullname, string abbrev, long long id, double lat, double lon) {
        Fullname = fullname;
        Abbrev = abbrev;
        Coords = Coordinates(id, lat, lon);
    }
};

//
// Functions:
//
bool LoadOpenStreetMap(string filename, XMLDocument& xmldoc);
int ReadMapNodes(XMLDocument& xmldoc, map<long long, Coordinates>& Nodes);
int ReadFootways(XMLDocument& xmldoc,
                 map<long long, Coordinates>& Nodes,
                 vector<FootwayInfo>& Footways);
int ReadUniversityBuildings(XMLDocument& xmldoc,
                            const map<long long, Coordinates>& Nodes,
                            vector<BuildingInfo>& Buildings);

My main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  /*setprecision*/
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include "graph.h"
#include "osm.h"
#include "application.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;


int main() {
  // maps a Node ID to it's coordinates (lat, lon)
  map<long long, Coordinates>  Nodes;
  // info about each footway, in no particular order
  vector<FootwayInfo>          Footways;
  // info about each building, in no particular order
  vector<BuildingInfo>         Buildings;
  XMLDocument                  xmldoc;

  cout << "** Navigating UIC open street map **" << endl;
  // cout << endl;
  cout << std::setprecision(8);

  string default_filename = "uic-2024.osm";
  string filename;

  // cout << "Enter map filename> ";
  // getline(cin, filename);

  if (filename == "") {
    filename = default_filename;
  }

  // Load XML-based map file
  if (!LoadOpenStreetMap(filename, xmldoc)) {
    cout << "**Error: unable to load open street map." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
  }

  // Read the nodes, which are the various known positions on the map:
  int nodeCount = ReadMapNodes(xmldoc, Nodes);

  // Read the footways, which are the walking paths:
  int footwayCount = ReadFootways(xmldoc, Nodes, Footways);

  // Read the university buildings:
  int buildingCount = ReadUniversityBuildings(xmldoc, Nodes, Buildings);

  // Stats
  assert(nodeCount == (int)Nodes.size());
  assert(footwayCount == (int)Footways.size());
  assert(buildingCount == (int)Buildings.size());

  // cout << endl;
  cout << "# of nodes: " << Nodes.size() << endl;
  cout << "# of footways: " << Footways.size() << endl;
  cout << "# of buildings: " << Buildings.size() << endl;

  // Build graph from input data
  graph<long long, double> G = buildGraph(Nodes, Footways, Buildings);

  // More stats
  cout << "# of vertices: " << G.NumVertices() << endl;
  cout << "# of edges: " << G.NumEdges() << endl;
  application(Buildings, G);

  cout << "** Done **" << endl;
  return 0;
}

My expected output (which I have):
Person 1's point:
UIC Academic and Residential Complex (ARC)
664275388
(41.87478, -87.650866)
Person 2's point:
Science & Engineering Offices (SEO)
151960667
(41.870851, -87.650375)
Destination Building:
Stevenson Hall (SH)
151676521
(41.872875, -87.650468)
Person 1's distance to dest: 0.13975891 miles
Path: 664275388->2412572929->1645208827->464345369->463814052->464748194->462010750->462010751->9862302685->9870872111->151676521
Person 2's distance to dest: 0.16077909 miles
Path: 151960667->1647971930->462010746->462010758->11257988853->464345492->462010740->9870872102->462010759->151676521

Why do I keep getting a Valgrind set address range perms warning in my code? -- It would have been better if you posted a [mcve] without all the commented code, and without mentioning anything about Dijkstra or priority queue.  Just the title alone, plus an edited version of your code without all the comments would have sufficed.  Valgrind has no idea what your project is all about -- it is simply reporting issues with your C++ code, which may or may not be legitimate.

I'll change the code. One moment

It still isn't a [mcve], where we could simply take the code, compile and run it, and see the issue.  Start with this.  This is basically your graph template class with a main that intantiates an instance of the class.  Does this give you valgrind messages?  If not, then slowly add code to the example at the link until you see the issue appear.

buildGraph uses undeclared idenfier nodes (lowercase n). It shouldn't compile.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Your question does not contain a lot of details about the valgrind aspects (e.g. missing the version of valgrind, the exact warning produced and the options you are using).
But on the last version of valgrind, the only warning that matches the string 'set address range perms' is produced when valgrind observes the allocation or mapping of an area of memory with a size > 256 MB.
This is just a warning, only shown when valgrind verbosity is > 0.
So, double check that it is normal that your code allocates or maps such a big memory area, and then all is fine.
